# Alternative to ZeroMQ+Protobuf (is ZeroMQ dead for Java?)

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, zeromq

I was looking for Message Queue for our Java project, and came to ZeroMQ+Protobuf
as ZeroMQ does not provide serializer, and we already use Protobuf.

However, while checking over ZeroMQ issues I found that Java binding `jzmq` is not released for 2 years [#442](https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq/issues/442)
While [`jeromq`Java implementation](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq)

> Based on libzmq 3.2.5.

That no Java solution at all for ZeroMQ 4.x. (Latest 3.x release was 2014/10/14)

Comment: jzmq has several commits in the last few months on github

Comment: ZeroMQ is fabulous for providing high-level abstractions to abstain from low-level / low-quality amateur attempts to dig into high-performance + low-latency SIG/MSG transport-plane. Why do you consider a non-functional feature ( such as a ser/des tool ) as a missing one for a SIG/MSG-service?

Answer (score 2):

[Nanomsg](http://nanomsg.org/documentation.html) was designed as a replacement and upgrade to ZeroMQ and has a couple Java bindings. Latest one was updated in February.

Comment: With all due respect, no, Sir. Martin Sustrik has breathed-in a lot of insights into nanomsg, but without an ambition to serve *(cit.:)* "as a replacement and upgrade". Plus, there is some uneasy re-organisation process in nanomsg git crowd in more recent months.

Comment: @user3666197 Not sure how closely you have been paying attention, but someone has taken up the helm and a 1.0 version has been released for the C++ binding. [The website provide a list of differences with ZeroMQ](http://nanomsg.org/documentation-zeromq.html) filled with steps nanomsg has made to be better than ZeroMQ. Even referring to parts of ZeroMQ as "architectural blunders"

Comment: **`TL;DR;`** but a part of the flow + interesting pieces of experience >>> http://sealedabstract.com/rants/nanomsg-postmortem-and-other-stories/ **There is no intention to compare one to the other, but to learn a lot from the pains and frustrations burried in an unstructured FOSS process.**